# Can't make reappear hidden divs in a navbar once a button is pressed with help of media queries

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries

I'm trying to reproduce [this responsive Navbar](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav_responsive.asp) offered by W3 schools.

So far everything works except that I don't get the other divs (which function as navigation option) to reappear as a vertical list.

I tried changing to background color of the first div (which should always appear no matter what) upon button press and it does work, meaning that the `onClick` of the `navigation` div does work. What I don't get is why won't the other divs show up?

Here is the relevant HTML code

```
<div id=navbar class="respNavBar">
    <div id="first">
        <a><b>TEST</b></a>
    </div>
    <div class="extra">
        <a><b>TEST</b></a>
    </div>
    <div class="extra">
        <a><b>TEST</b></a>
    </div>
    <div class="extra">
        <a><b>TEST</b></a>
    </div>

    <div class=navigation href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="showRespBar()">
        <a><b>...</b></a>
    </div>
```

CSS CODE

```
.greetingsText {
    font-family: Raleway;
    font-size: 50px;
}

.greetings {
    box-shadow: 3px 6px #232323;
    margin-right: 67%;
    min-width: 165px;
}

#navbar {
    height: 55px;
    background-color: #393939;
    box-shadow: 3px 6px #232323;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center; /* this makes shit center align vertically*/
    min-width: 375px;
}

#navbar div:hover {
    background-color: #a4a4a4;
}

.navigation {
    display: none;

}

#navbar div {
    height: 100%;
}

a {
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: block;
    font-family: Raleway;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center; /*this makes shit center horizaontally*/
}


.container {
    margin-left: 12%;
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-right: 12%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 750px) {
    #navbar {
        display: block;
    }

    #navbar div:not(#first):not(.navigation)  {display: none;}


    #first {
        float: left;
        display: block;
    }

    .navigation {
        display: block;
        float: right;
    }

}
@media screen and (max-width: 750px){

    .extra {
        float: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
    }

}
```

JS CODE

```
function showRespBar() {

    var className = document.getElementById("navbar").className;

    if (className === "respNavBar") {
        document.getElementById("navbar").className += "additional";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("navbar").className = "respNavBar";
    }

    alert(className);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible issue i found in your JS code, inside `if` condition,

`document.getElementById("navbar").className += "additional";` should be `document.getElementById("navbar").className += " additional";`

You are missing a space, due to which `respNavBaradditional` class gets applied to navbar instead of `respNavBar addition`.